# How can I ensure my c# string ends in a period?

Tags: c#

I have c# strings looking like this:

```
"abc";
"def.";
```

When I read these into another variable I need some simple way to check the last character of the string and if it's not a period then append a period to that string.

Does anyone have any ideas of a simple way I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class StringExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string EnsureEndsWithDot(this string str)
        {
            if (!str.EndsWith(".")) return str + ".";
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @fardjad - This looks very clean. How do I use the method?

Comment: This is an `String Extension Method`. You can use it on every string. For example: `string MyString="abc";MyString = MyString.EnsureEndsWithDot();`

Answer (score 9):

```
if (!str.EndsWith(".")) str += ".";
```

Is there a reason you can't do this a different way, though?

Comment: Like the comment police mentioned on mine, this will blow up with null  input.

Comment: No reason to check for null input if there's no way you're ever going to be calling it on null input.  Need to know where and how it's gonna be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace StackoverflowConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(StringExtensionMethods.EnsureEndsWithDot("abc"));
        }
    }
}
namespace StackoverflowConsoleApp
{

    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains string extensions
    /// </summary>
    public static class StringExtensionMethods
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// constant dot
        /// </summary>
        private const string dot = ".";

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures the string ends with dot character
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"><see cref="string"/>Takes a string parameter</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="string"/>returns a string parameter</returns>
        public static string EnsureEndsWithDot(this string text)
        {
            if (!text.EndsWith(dot))
            {
                return string.Format("{0}{1}", text, dot);
            }

            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do...

```
// Appends a ., or if myString was empty to begin with, makes it "."
myString = (myString != null && myString.Length != 0 && myString[myString.Length - 1] == '.') ? myString : (myString ?? "") + ".";
```